# Prometheus node exporter won't provide disk volume information

Tags: prometheus, prometheus-node-exporter

Prometheus node exporter shows

```
"node_filesystem_device_error" = 1
```

for additional disks (dirs) except

```
/
```

like device

```
/dev/vdb
```

mounted to directory

```
/dir
```

Any one have the same is?

Answer (score 0):

I had the very same problem. But in context of node-exporter running in docker.

And managed to fix it by adding the mount point to bind mounted volumes of the container as:

```
volumes:
  - /:/rootfs:ro
  - /dir:/dir:ro
  - ...others...
```